# 1 Question Limit

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, rate-limiting

I asked my first question 5 days ago and have not asked a question since. It got 1 upvote, and was answered in comments. When I went to ask a new question 5 days later it says:

> You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited. For more information, visit the Help Center.

So, I can post a question 1 week later, but the thing I don't understand, is my one question had one upvote, so I'm above zero on average.

Does anyone know if this is just the way it goes or is the algorithm messed up?

Comment: Did you delete any of your questions?

Comment: Independent of this question: when someone answered your question in a comment, please encourage that person to post an answer instead or do it yourself when they don't want to.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I just have to wait 1 week

Comment: It's a duplicate and it answers your question. Have a look at the very last [bullet point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/11682469): "If you opt to [*delete* your account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) and then later return to the site, your ability to ask questions may be [limited to one question per week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/102937) until you have demonstrated an ability to ask useful questions." The last link explains why it's one week, but the post it links to is on MSE, not MSO.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks @JeanneDark

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks an afwul lot like you've been caught by the [anti-recidivism-system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/anti-recidivism-system/info)

> The system that deals with users who request deletion in order to evade restrictions that are placed on their accounts at the time of deletion.
>
> We log data on such accounts at time of deletion, which is then referenced should a new account from the same individual be created. If the user was suspended at the time of deletion, then the new account will inherit the remainder of the original suspension. If the user was blocked from posting questions at the time of deletion, then the recreated account will be restricted to posting only one question per week until the quality of their contributions is demonstrated.

This restricts people who've had an account previously and deleted it to try to avoid restrictions from simply creating a new account and continuing to ask poor quality questions. Trying to avoid things this way as you've discovered is rather counterproductive.